# JavaFx FXML load file issues with setting root

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx, scenebuilder

New to javaFx and wanting to use scenebuilder for GUI development, i've come across an issue with no luck searching the website nor the web in general for my problem, although similar questions have been asked, thought a different perspective could be needed. I am trying to load an FXML file through Netbeans after a quick build to test functionality so the code is simple, but i cannot get the root file to be set in the controller.  my code is the following
    public class Divergex extends Application {

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("DivergexGUI.fxml"));


    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    scene.setRoot(root);

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

Ive tried suggestions in changing fxroot to a Vbox with no luck, i continue to get a Load exception on the compile :

> Exception in Application start method...
>   Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: Root hasn't been set. Use method setRoot() before load.

yet when i use

```
scene.setRoot(root);
```

the same exception is experienced

i've narrowed the issue down to the fact that my FXML file is unable to be set as a root in the Parent object but have had no luck in tackling this.  Any suggestions would be great thanks.

Comment: Can you show the fxml file, or at least the root element for it?

Comment: yes, here is the complete file, again, simple just to get a working form          




<fx:root type="VBox" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="divergex.DivergexGUIController">

Comment: Why are you using `<fx:root>`?

Comment: it was the default build for Scenebuilder and setting a controller, i am new to JavaFx so the tutorials i went through had me using those to write my FXML, if there is a better option i would love to use it i just couldnt find a clear solution as of yet.

Comment: I'm not a (frequent) SceneBuilder user. I thought `AnchorPane` was the default root element for SceneBuilder. That was bad enough - `AnchorPane` is pretty useless for most applications. `<fx:root>` is actually a much worse choice as a default; it's really only for very particular use cases.

Comment: @James_D bro I m also new to JavaFX. Why do I need to use Parent Node, what does the FXMLLoader.load() do actually, does it return the root node in the .fxml file, if so, it should be VBox root = FXMLLoader.load (....)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`<fx:root>` specifies a "dynamic root" for your FXML file; this means the root of the FXML file is an object that is set on the loader prior to loading the file. This is typically used for custom controls, where you want the control to be a subclass of `Node` that can be instantiated using regular Java code, but want to define its layout using FXML. Proper use of `<fx:root>` (or at least an example of how it can be used) is shown in the [standard documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/toc.htm). In particular, if you use `<fx:root>` you must:

1. Create an `FXMLLoader` instance, instead of using the static convenience `FXMLLoader.load(URL)` method
2. Call setRoot(...) on that instance, and pass in the object that is to be the root of the FXML.

For standard FXML use, you just use a regular instance declaration as the root. Almost every example available works this way: probably the best place to start is the [official tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/fxml-tutorial/why_use_fxml.htm#JFXMG137). In your case, since you want a `VBox`, you probably just need

```
<VBox xmlns="javafx.com/javafx/8"; xmlns:fx="javafx.com/fxml/1"; fx:controller="divergex.DivergexGUIController">
<!-- ... -->
</VBox>
```

**Edit** If Netbeans is giving you issues, I recommend using Eclipse with the [e(fx)clipse plugin](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/efxclipse#.U3mLC61dWNM). There's a very barebones, but pretty much all you need, [tutorial](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Efxclipse/Tutorials).

Comment: I tried using AnchorPane as my root, but it doesn't support a controller, and VBox does not support a controller either, but upon compiling with your VBox declaration, i had a successful build of my GUI with button functionality, Thank you.  Just not sure if this is orthodox as My IDE is claiming that VBox does not support a controller property.

Comment: Explain "doesn't support a controller"... you just add an `fx:controller` attribute to the root element of the FXML.

Comment: correct, but in adding that attribute, Netbeans displays a warning "....Class 'javafx.scene.layout.VBox' does not support property 'controller'..."

Comment: Sounds like you may have put `controller='...'` instead of `fx:controller='...'`?

Comment: nope used `fx:controller` funny thing is it works just fine that way only it displays the warning.

Comment: Sounds like a NetBeans bug (or possibly misconfiguration). I don't use NetBeans much (did for a while when Eclipse didn't have Java 8 support but switched back as soon as it did) - maybe post to a NetBeans forum. Anyway, it is the correct, and standard, way and clearly works. Good luck with your project.

Comment: Normal eclipse user, switched to netbeans for the JavaFx learning process, thanks for the help much appreciated.

Comment: bro I m also new to JavaFX. Why do I need to use Parent Node, what does the FXMLLoader.load() do actually, does it return the root node in the .fxml file, if so, it should be VBox root = FXMLLoader.load (....)

Comment: @Tanvir `FXMLLoader.load()` does return the root element of the FXML file. `VBox` is a subclass of `Parent`, so `Parent` is the correct type to use unless you specifically need to access `VBox` functionality (which is highly unlikely in this context).

Comment: Thank u, ohh I guess in Java its called Upcasting (if I m not wrong), but this way I cant access the instance variable for the VBox.

Comment: @Tanvir Yes, this is upcasting. What do you mean "I can't access the instance variable for the `VBox`"? If you do `Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(...)` then `root` is a reference to the `VBox`.

Comment: as far as I remember, upcasting doesnt allow to access class variables of the child class(if I m not wrong) but DownCasting does. Upcasting is putting ur child class reference to any Parent class, hence only instance variable of Parent class is accessible.

Comment: @Tanvir From a reference of type `Parent` you can only access members (typically methods, your variables should all be `private` anyway) that are declared in `Parent`. But why do you need to access anything else?

Comment: yes, u r right, I just wonder when to us UPCASTING. I mean the Best Practice for Upcasting. Some say when its the "IS-A" relationship, use Upcasting.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214364/discussion-between-james-d-and-tanvir).

Comment: @Tanvir Probably not the place for a tutorial on basic Java.

Answer (score 4):

uncheck id::root in scence builder
or change id::root to vbox

Answer (score 0):

Just you should not use fx:root construct in scene builder.
so remove this line of code from the fxml file.

For example: `<fx:root prefHeight="246.0" prefWidth="479.0" type="AnchorPane" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.141" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.mycontroller">`

Comment: For example? You let the answer unfinished.

Answer (score 0):

When you create FXML file with the help of Scene Builder. It uses fx: root as a pane.  Replace it with Anchor Pane

```
   AnchorPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.controller.Controller
```

It works for me. Anyone can try, it may help for you